# Program skips if statements

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, fflush

I've written a program with a lot of `if` sections.It´s written with Visual Studio 2013(scanf_s).
It skips some `if` sections though these are met. Can you please tell me why?
My suspicion: The first `scanf` command is executed cleanly. The other `scanf` commands don't work. I can't input anything. The program goes strictly on. When I insert `fflush(stdin)` between the `scanf` commands, it works. I heard bad things about `fflsuh` because of this I wanna ask: How can I solve it in another way?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char versand='n', stammkunde='t';
double warenwert=1;
printf("Wieviel kostet die Ware?");
scanf_s("%lf", &warenwert);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Wird die Ware abgeholt?(y,n)");
scanf_s("%c", &versand);
if (versand == 'n')
{
    if (warenwert < 100)
    {
        warenwert = warenwert + 7;
    }
    printf("Expressversand?(y,n");
    scanf_s("%c", &versand);
        //fflush(stdin); 

    if (versand == 'y')
    {
        warenwert = warenwert + 10;
    }
}
printf("Stammkunde?(y,n)");
scanf_s("%c", &stammkunde);
if (stammkunde = 'y')
{
    warenwert = warenwert * 0, 97;
}
printf("Endpreis inkl. Versandkosten:%lf", warenwert);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

P.S: Program output screenshot here: http://i.gyazo.com/01471ce3d563837f526fbcab8363e1f2.png

Comment: can we add the output of your programm?

Comment: try `scanf_s(" %c", &versand, 1);`

Comment: If the scope of the if statement isn't executed the conditions aren't met. Did you try and echo back what it received?

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: And please also format your code when posting here.

Comment: `if (stammkunde = 'y')` is wrong. It should be `if (stammkunde == 'y')`.

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return value of `scanf_s`? Then you don't need to rely on your suspicions.

Comment: output screenshot here:  http://i.gyazo.com/01471ce3d563837f526fbcab8363e1f2.png

Comment: you need to flush the stdin... check here for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248442/flushing-stdin-after-every-input-which-approach-is-not-buggy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("Wird die Ware abgeholt?(y,n)");
scanf_s("%c", &versand);
```

When you enter input and hit the ENTER key, a character and return key are placed in the input buffer, they are namely: the entered character and the newline character.The character gets consumed by the `scanf_s` but the newline remains in the input buffer.

Further,

```
printf("Expressversand?(y,n");
scanf_s("%c", &versand);
```

Your next `scanf_s` for reading the character just reads/consumes the newline and hence never waits for user input.

**Way 1:** Solution is to consume the extra newline by using:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &versand);
         ^  ---- note the space!
```

**Way 2:** You can try this also-

```
fflush(stdin); // flush the stdin before scanning input!
printf("Expressversand?(y,n");
scanf_s("%c", &versand);
```

Fix this following bugs also-

```
printf("Stammkunde?(y,n)");
scanf_s(" %c", &stammkunde); // give space before %c
if (stammkunde == 'y') // for comparison use == not =
{
    warenwert = warenwert * 0, 97;
}
```

**Edit:** In this equation

```
warenwert = warenwert * 0, 97;
```

`warenwert * 0` have evaluated first, due to high priority. so

```
warenwert = 0 , 97;
```

Here `=` has high priority then `,` operator. so `warenwert = 0` is assigned first. So you will get the result is `0` whenever this `if (stammkunde = 'y')` condition is true

**Sample Run1:**-

```
sathish@ubuntu:~/c/basics$ ./a.out 
Wieviel kostet die Ware?
2
Wird die Ware abgeholt?(y,n)
n
Expressversand?(y,n)
y
Stammkunde?(y,n)
n
Endpreis inkl. Versandkosten:19.000000
```

**Run 2:**-

```
sathish@ubuntu:~/c/basics$ ./a.out 
Wieviel kostet die Ware?
2
Wird die Ware abgeholt?(y,n)
n
Expressversand?(y,n)
y
Stammkunde?(y,n) // here your input value becomes 19, due to last condition it becomes zero!
y
Endpreis inkl. Versandkosten:0.000000
```

Comment: `scanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for parameters of  `%c`,  `%s`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the standards (although it might work as expected on most systems)

Comment: @sathish thx for your answer! I changed all the things. The next problem is, that i always get the value back i´ve typed in at the beginning. in the if conditions are calculations which are not considered. :/

Comment: @HaraldWiesinger what value you are getting? same as input or 97?

Comment: The behavior of `fflush` is not defined for input streams; the operation is nonsensical.  If it does clear the input stream, that's by accident, not design.

Comment: @JohnBode It is not a  standard but it is defined in MSVC. [fflush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx)

Comment: this `warenwert = warenwert * 0, 97;`also won't compile, not even on a german machine.

Comment: @Sathish and what would it mean?

Comment: @speising See my New edits! it is working correctly! Executing all if conditions. i am using gcc on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: not so correctly if you arrive at a final price of 0.0 instead of 18.43.

Answer (score 0):

And here comes **Way 3** comes :

After scanf_s something it changes stdin->_base and stdin->_cnt and that cause thatproblem and if you want to solve it you can write `std->_base="\0";` and `std->_cnt=0;` after every time you used scanf_s for something. But if you read chars from string it can be different situation i said that for read one variable value.