# What can cause a program to ignore the user's input

Tags: c

No matter what option I choose, I'm always prompted to enter a new shift value (as if I entered 1 as my choice). Why does this code ignore the option that I selected?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 500
int getUserChoice()
{
    int decision = 0;

    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |\n");
    printf("| 2) Encrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 3) Decrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 4) Quit                     |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("Option: ");
    scanf("%d", &decision);
    if(decision == 0 || decision >= 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return decision;
}
int getShift()
{
    int key = 3;
    printf("Enter new shift value: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
   return 0;
}
void getString(char buf[])
{
    int act;
    act = SIZE - 1;
    int count[26] = {0};
    fgets(buf, act, stdin);
    return;
}
void encrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf);++i)
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] + shift;
    }
    return;
}
void decrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf); ++i)
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] - shift;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    char userStr[SIZE];
    int number = 0;
    getUserChoice();
    int shift = 0;
    if(number = 1)
    {
        getShift();

    }
    if (number = 2)
   {
        getString(userStr);
        encrypt(userStr, shift);
    }
    if (number = 3)
    {
        getString(userStr);
        decrypt(userStr, shift);
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When I compile and run this, it prints the menu before asking for any input.

Comment: 1) `getUserChoice();` --> `number = getUserChoice();`

Comment: I asked for help with the wrong thing, I've had a lot of problems with this recently. What I meant to ask help with was why, no matter what option I choose when prompted, am I always prompted to enter a new shift value, when that should only be prompted when the user selects option 1.

Comment: 2) `if(number = 1)
    {
        getShift();

    }` --> `if(number == 1)
    {
        shift = getShift();

    }`,  `scanf("%d", &key);
   return 0;` --> `scanf("%d", &key);
   return key;`

Comment: 3) `scanf("%d", &decision);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &decision);` :p

Comment: 4) `main` needs loop and Display results.

Answer (score 1):

That looks a lot like homework and you didn't seem to make much effort on finding the issues, but here we go.. There are several flaws on the code:

#### 1) Ignoring return values:

Some of your functions, `getUserChoice` and `getShift`, are supposed to return a value but those values are completely ignored in the code. You are not assigning it to any local variables and they are not modifying anything outside their scope, so whatever value is being returned is getting lost.

The code:

```
if(number = 1){
    getShift();
}
```

Should be:

```
if(number == 1){
    shift = getShift();
}
```

Which brings me to another big mistake, reason of many headaches on C when it happens unintentionally:

#### 2) Mistakenly writing the assignment operator '=' where a comparison operator '==' is required:

The assignment operator returns a value: the left operand value after assignment. So the expression `if(number = 1)` is valid and will evaluate to true every time, since the returning value of the assignment is always 1. `if(number == 1)` however, will only evaluate to true when `number` is equal to 1. I find it useful to make comparisons "Yoda-Style", like `if(1 == number)` to avoid those kind of mistakes (that can easily happen on a typo). They are hard to track, since the code is valid, but the behavior is not the expected. Using the "Yoda-Style" comparison, you would get a compiler error if you mistyped `if(1 = number)`, since that's an invalid assignment.

#### 3) Not properly filtering the user input:

On the function `getUserChoice` you have the following conditional statement to check if the input is valid (when invalid it defaults to the "Quit" option):

```
if(decision == 0 || decision >= 4)
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, since decision is a `signed int`, negative values are valid. You don't account for those. The following addresses that:

```
if(decision <= 0 || decision >= 4)
{
    return 0;
}
```

#### 4) `getShift` doesn't return the shift value:

You used `scanf` on the `getShift` function to get a shift value, but returned 0. You should return the `key` value instead.

#### 5) Unused variable at `getString` + Wrong size argument on `fgets`:

You declared an array of 0's on `getString` which serves no purpose on it. Also, from `fgets` man page:

> fgets()  reads in at most **one less than size** characters from stream and
>          stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading  stops  after  an
>          EOF  or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>          A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last  character  in
>          the buffer.

So you don't really need to subtract 1 from SIZE, since it will already account for the null character.

#### 6) Not clearing the `stdin` before calling `fgets`:

After the call to `scanf("%d",...);`, you will have a hanging newline character in your `stdin`. That's because the format string parsed to `scanf` there only instructs it to read any number of decimal digits, not including the newline that follows those.

That hanging newline would cause your `fgets` to quit before getting any user input. You need to clear the `stdin` by reading the hanging characters from a previous `scanf` call. In the example, this is being done by this loop:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
    //Clearing Stdin
}
```

An alternative is to use:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c"); //Consume all characters up to \n (if present) then consume exactly one char ('\n' itself)
```

#### 7) Not using a loop in main to prompt the user repeatedly:

You only prompt the user once, do what is asked and quit, instead of asking the user repeatedly for options until he asks to quit.

#### 8) Unnecessary `return` statements on the end of `void` returning functions:

`void` return functions will return when they reach their end, so there is no need to add a `return` statement unless you are returning before the end of the function body.

The code below is edited to fix the mentioned issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 500
int getUserChoice()
{
    int decision = 0;

    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |\n");
    printf("| 2) Encrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 3) Decrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 4) Quit                     |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("Option: ");
    scanf("%d", &decision);
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        //Clearing Stdin
    }
    if(decision <= 0 || decision >= 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return decision;
}

int getShift()
{
    int key = 3;
    printf("Enter new shift value: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        //Clearing Stdin
    }
    return key;
}
void getString(char *buf)
{
    fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin);
    return;
}
void encrypt(char *buf, int shift)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= (strlen(buf)-1);++i)
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] + shift;
    }
    return;
}
void decrypt(char *buf, int shift)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= (strlen(buf)-1); ++i)
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] - shift;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    char userStr[SIZE];
    int shift = 3;

    while(1){
        int number = getUserChoice();
        if(number == 1)
        {
            shift = getShift();

        }
        if (number == 2)
        {
            getString(userStr);
            printf("Message: %s\n", userStr);
            encrypt(userStr, shift);
            printf("Shifted Message: %s\n", userStr);
        }
        if (number == 3)
        {
            getString(userStr);
            printf("Shifted Message: %s\n", userStr);
            decrypt(userStr, shift);
            printf("Message: %s\n", userStr);
        }
        if (number == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 I still use it, guess I got used to it so it doesn't look that bad to me, but I can see why people would disagree. Guess if you compile with `-Wall` you should be safe..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It was my mistake, I was thinking of the comparison as "lower or equal", instead of just "lower than". The error was hidden because of the newline character, so all visible characters except the newline were being shifted on the tests. I'll edit it out!

Comment: "... flush the `stdin`? Oh, yeh, I know how to do that! `fflush(stdin);`!"... The very presense of the word "flush" will cause some people to think this.

Comment: Also, `scanf("%*[^\n]");` is the shortcut; you don't need that loop.

Comment: @Seb Although `fflush(stdin)` could work depending on the implementation, take a loot at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/6676042) and [this another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38325926/6676042): It isn't defined in the standards, so its behavior is undefined and it should be avoided..

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: @Seb I apologize, I misunderstood your comment and was thinking you were saying the OP should use `fflush`. I see your point and will soon edit it so it doesn't mislead people into using it.

Comment: One possible alternative would be to describe the entire action of the loop, e.g. to *(read and) discard the remainder of the line*. You could start by explaining that `scanf("%d", ...)` instructs the computer to read *a sequence of decimal digits*, **not** the newline that follows it; subsequent calls to `scanf` will come across that newline later, so it needs to be read and discarded. This can be done using `scanf("%*[^\n]");`. I'd recommend it in `getUserChoice` and `getShift`, rather than `getString`, as that'd decouple user interface refactoring from logic; there's a bug otherwise...

Comment: The bug: consider `int main() { char userStr[SIZE]; getString(userStr); printf("That string is: %s\n", userStr); }`...

Comment: @Seb That sounds good! I'll edit the answer as soon as I get back from work (I'm on my phone). I didn't get to test it yet, but I guess you're right about the bug: the user is going to get stuck in the loop until he types enter, right?

Comment: @Seb I used other words in the paragraph about clearing the `stdin` as suggested, but couldn't get `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` nor `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");` to work as you suggested. Theoretically they should work, but for some reason they are not getting rid of the hanging newline. For that reason I kept the `getchar` loop approach and wrote a question regarding `scanf` not working for that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41928145/6676042). If you have any clues, take a look at it!
Thanks :)

Comment: @IanC What do you think the `[` directive is *supposed* to do when it encounters an empty field?

Comment: @IanC There is a reason I wrote `scanf("%*[^\n]");`, you invented the `\n` on the end... Learn `scanf` before you try to use it; the same goes with ALL features of C, since undefined behaviour is EVERYWHERE!

Comment: @Seb You wrote `scanf("%*[^\n]");`, which by itself wouldn't work neither, leaving the newline hanging. I found those two other patterns while looking for ways to fix it. Unfortunately, some [older](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070821/6676042) answers and [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17248442/6676042) were misleading. They didn't count with the fact that the first pattern failure would quit `scanf` before it consumed the newline. It is no undefined behavior, actually pretty defined according to the man page, I just didn't know it yet, since I don't use this command frequently.

Comment: @IanC Yes. Better yet, a straight-forward solution to removing a single character would be to simply call `getchar()`. I wouldn't describe this as *clearing*, either, as the C standard uses that term to describe a *zeroing* operation on flags, for example: *"The `clearerr` function clears the end-of-file and error indicators for the stream pointed to by stream."* If you're looking for a more standard term, you'll find the term "advance" used in [the spec for `fgetc`](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.7.1) (among others).

Answer (score 0):

The are two things in the code that cause it to ignore the user input.

First, the `getUserChoice` function returns a value, but `main` doesn't store or use the return value. The function call should look like this:

```
number = getUserChoice();
```

Second, a single equal sign `if(number = 1)` acts as an assignment. It sets `number` to the value `1`. To compare `number` with `1`, use the equality operator, e.g.

```
if ( number == 1 )
```

Note that any decent compiler will generate a warning when you mistakenly put an assignment inside an `if` statement. You should make sure that you enable all warnings (use `-Wall` with gcc or clang, `/W4` with microsoft), and fix all of the warnings. If you ignore compiler warnings, you'll get nowhere fast.

There are other problems in your code, but those are the two problems that are causing the user input to be ignored.