# Why aren't scanf("%*[^\n]\n"); and scanf("%*[^\n]%*c"); clearing a hanging newline?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, fgets

After a call to `scanf("%d", &variable);` we are left with a newline hanging at the *stdin*, which should be cleared before a call to `fgets`, or we end up feeding it a newline and making it return prematurely.

I've found answers suggesting using `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` after the first call to `scanf` to discard the newline and others suggesting using `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");`. Theoretically, both should work: The first would consume everything that isn't a newline (but not including the newline itself) and then consume **exactly** one character (the newline). The second would consume everything that isn't a newline (not including it) and then `\n`, a whitespace character, would instruct `scanf` to read every whitespace characters up to the first non-whitespace character.

However, as much as I've seem those approaches working in some answers, I couldn't get them to work here (codes below).

**Why neither of the `scanf` approaches worked?**

Tested on:
Ubuntu Linux - `gcc` 5.4.0

#### `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");` approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int number;
    char buffer[1024];

    printf("Write number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    //Clearing stdin?
    scanf("%*[^\n]\n");

    printf("Write phrase: \n");
    fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);

    printf("\n\nYou wrote:%u and \"%s\"\n", number, buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./bug 
Write number: 
2
Write phrase: 


You wrote:2 and "
"
```

#### `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int number;
    char buffer[1024];

    printf("Write number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    //Clearing stdin?
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Write phrase: \n");
    fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);

    printf("\n\nYou wrote:%u and \"%s\"\n", number, buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./bug2 
Write number: 
3
Write phrase: 


You wrote:3 and "
"
```

---

The following approach was the only one that worked the way it was expected to:

#### Working approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int number;
    char buffer[1024];

    printf("Write number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    //Clearing stdin!
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        //Discard up to (and including) newline
    }

    printf("Write phrase: \n");
    fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);

    printf("\n\nYou wrote:%u and \"%s\"\n", number, buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./notbug 
Write number: 
4
Write phrase: 
phrase :D


You wrote:4 and "phrase :D
"
```

Comment: you may use fgets(or gets) to read the input into buffer, then use sscanf() to get the number.

Comment: @Shiping Sure, there are other approaches to get this code working. But the point of the question is why the `scanf` approaches of clearing the hanging newline aren't working as it would be expected.

Comment: @Shiping: **never ever** use `gets`. It is dangerous and not part of the standard (anymore).

Comment: @IanC: So do you notice any correlation why experienced C programmers tell to use `fgets` instead of using `scanf`?

Comment: @Olaf Yeah! `fgets` is more straight-up to the point and doesn't create that issue of hanging characters on the *stdin* buffer. I actually ran into this doubt while writing an answer to a question that used `scanf`

Comment: @Olaf thanks. I hardly write interactive C programs now. even if i do need some simple input from users, i usually ask users to give as commandline arguments.

Comment: Voting to close because `scanf` is behaving as it's specified according to the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that the scanf pattern `%[^\n]`  matches *ONE OR MORE* characters that are not newlines.  So if the next character *is* a newline, the pattern will fail and `scanf` will return immediately without reading anything.  Add a `*` doesn't change that basic fact.  So it turns out you can't do this with only one call, you need two:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");
```

Note that putting a bare newline into the scan pattern is almost always not useful -- it causes scanf to read and discard all whitespace until it sees a non-whitespace character (which will be left in the input buffer).  Particularly if you try to use it in an interactive program, it will appear to hang until you enter a non-blank line.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes sense now why `scanf` didn't seem to discard anything at all from the *stdin*, it was actually failing right at the beginning. I could confirm what you were saying on the first line of `[` conversion specifier description ("Matches a **nonempty** sequence of characters from the specified set...") and on the "Return Value" section :)

Comment: Corner case: `scanf("%*[^\n]");` returns because it encountered a `'\n'`, end-of-file or input error.  `scanf("%*c");` is OK to call after the first 2 of those 3.  In the last, rare case, `scanf("%*c");` may consume a non- `'\n'` character.  Checking the return value of `scanf()` is recommended.

Comment: @chux: If the first `scanf` gets an input error, then so will the second, as there's no `clearerr` call between them.  Same with an EOF.

Comment: C explicitly says "If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, _or_ if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF."  There is _not_ a corresponding _or_ with the error indicator:  "If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF".  So the 2nd `scanf()` may return a non-EOF, even though the first returned EOF due to an input error - with/without an intervening `clearerr()`.